# Set the request's content-type using AFNetworking 2's AFHTTPRequestOperationManager?

Tags: afnetworking-2

I've been attempting to talk to a JSON API over HTTP using AFNetworking 2.0. The examples I found recommended the use of `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager`, so I implemented the following pseudocode:

```
manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://test-api.localdev/"]];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
params = @{
    @"username": @"Drarok",
    @"token": @"1234-abcd"
};
[manager GET:@"transactions" parameters:params success:[…] failure:[…]];
```

Unfortunately, it appears that the `AFJSONRequestSerializer` does not (or perhaps *can* not) set the Content-Type, and I am unable to find a way to manually do so.

As such, the API rejects my request with an "HTTP 415 unsupported media type" error.

Other, similar questions are caused by the server *response* not being application/json, but this question is about the request headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by an incorrect API server asserting that *all* requests had a `Content-Type: application/json` header. AFNetworking will correctly avoid setting that header for `HEAD`, `GET`, or `DELETE` requests.